# Is this RFID card? How to write and read data to this card?

Tags: android, rfid

I've been tasked to write and read data to this card. Vendor gave me Intelligent Tablet Payment Terminal i9300 and expect to write and read data to this card below. Intelligent Tablet Payment Terminal i9300 is Android based. It comes with its own SDK which poorly documented. What card is this and how do I even begin?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is an RFID card.

A lot of information can be derived from the documentation of the terminal you specified [Intelligent Tablet Payment Terminal i9300](http://www.urovo.com/html/2013-10-30-2013103005231932812529.html).

1. The card and the reader is tuned to work in **High Frequency(HF) range** of *10-20Mhz*, specifically **13.56MHz**. It is a **read-write card** and hence the *terminal* provided to you must also be a *read/write capable*.
2. I am not aware with the documentation provided to you but typical RFID card can store about **2kB of data max.**, which will be sufficient to store a customers *credits/balance points*. The specific customer will be identified by the **unique RFID number** mapped to his name.

You can read more on RFID read/write at [How can I write data on UHF RFID tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18031632/how-can-i-write-data-on-uhf-rfid-tags) and [Can I write or modify data on an RFID tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501302/can-i-write-or-modify-data-on-an-rfid-tag)

You can sort-out your basic RFID queries from [How do RFID systems work?](http://www.impinj.com/resources/about-rfid/how-do-rfid-systems-work/) and [RFID Journal](http://www.rfidjournal.com/site/faqs#Anchor-53283)

Comment: Is the card that I showed in the question above can be read by Intelligent Tablet Payment Terminal i9300?

Comment: Yes definitely it can be.